# Find overlapping List in 2 Lists of Lists

Tags: list

I would like to find overlapping lists in two lists of lists.

```
ListLeft = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['x', 'y'], ['one', 'two', 'three']]

ListRight = [['h', 'i', 'j'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7'], ['x', 'y']]
```

Someone might have a solution to find/print content of overlapping lists and lists which are not in both lists

Maybe this is possible without importing modules.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved by using loop:

```
overlap = []
for ll in ListLeft:
    for lr in ListRight:
        if ll == lr:
            overlap.append(ll)
            break

print overlap

>>> [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['x', 'y']]
```